# Powershell if condition to validate if a String with special charcs is NULL or EMPTY

Tags: powershell, github-actions, powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

I have a github secret which has value like below

```
Azuresecret is  <publishData><publishProfile profileName="a00008dfdgdfhfg" - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy" publishUrl="a00008w543tgddg" <databases /></publishProfile></publishData>
```

Now i am trying to validate if the secret is empty or Null using powershell
However i get Many error messages like this

```
  ... g]::IsNullOrEmpty("<publishData><publishProfile profileName="a00008-a ...
   +                                                                  ~
   Missing ')' in method call.

 Missing closing ')' in expression.
      At E:\_temp\0007a890-9ecb-4cce-b1e.ps1:10 char:90
    + ... a><publishProfile profileName="a00008-accountsfunctionapp-dev - Web D ...
      +                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement.
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You forgot to post the code that errors out

Comment: What is mysterious about `Missing ')' in method call` ?

Comment: `"<publishData><publishProfile profileName="` is a string with double quotes and the `a00008` is outside the string and causing problems. What are you doing that your XML content is being read as a PowerShell source code string? You need something from [Including quotes in strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#including-quote-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: i used singlequotes while comparing and it helped